# Dynamic Option for chosen in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-chosen

I am using chosen in angularjs.

I created a select as follows. and I need to changes the options dynamically.

```
<select class="sel-bx" chosen dataload="aListOfSampleIds.length" multiple selecteditm="sampleIdList" ng-model="sampleIdList" 
        ng-options="sampleIds.sample_id as sampleIds.sample_id
        for sampleIds in aListOfSampleIds | unique:'sample_id'" data-placeholder = " " >
</select>
```

In the directive i wrote

```
 $(".chosen-container").unbind('keyup').bind('keyup',function(e) {
                    //console.log('sfddf');
                    var searchStr = $('.chosen-container .search-field input').val();
                    console.log(searchStr);
                    if (searchStr.length > 2) {
                        console.log("Hi");
                        //Need to change the options in the list here
                        $rootScope.aListOfSampleIds =['sample_id','llll'];
                    }
                });
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Once when I used chosen, I had to put in my directive following code in order to change it dynamically. Not sure what it means, I didn't investigate, also, not sure if it will resolve your problem, but, you could try and see.

```
app.directive('chosen', function ($timeout) {
var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {

  $timeout(function () {
    element.chosen();
  }, 0, false);

};

  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: linker
  };
});
```